# shell script stop error

Tags: linux, shell

I have the following script and I want the script to stop executing on line x if line x encounters an error, how do I do that?

```
pvcreate /dev/$1
vgextend VolGroup00 /dev/$1
lvextend --size +$2 /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00
resize2fs /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `set -e` somewhere before executing this part.

Answer (score 12):

Add the following to the top.

```
set -e
```

After executing that line, the shell will exit if any line returns an error code. `set +e` will turn this back off again (i.e. switch back to continuing regardless of any error return codes).

See http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/writing-robust-shell-scripts.html for further details.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to query each step you have to check their return code. This means you will have to understand what the return codes for each query is (might be different for each). The example below checks vgextend for error code -1, then returns -1 itself.

```
pvcreate /dev/$1
vgextend VolGroup00 /dev/$1

if [ $? == -1 ]; then
      echo "vgextend returned an error"
      exit -1;
fi

lvextend --size +$2 /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00
resize2fs /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00
```

Set -e might be overkill, as some errors may be tolerable under certain circumstances. In the example below, the rm will return an error if thefile does not exist, but it's ok to continue (Yes, I know we could a conditional delete, but the example is meant to illustrate the point being made.)

```
# delete the file, it it exists
rm thefile
# create the file
touch thefile
```

Comment: I would advise to mark these likely-to-fail commands separately, like `rm somefile || true`. In this case `set -e` won't trigger.